# Bootstrap 4 Carousel - indicators not appearing (controls and jumbotron container working fine)

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I can't get the carousel indicators to show. I think it's something to do with my use of the jumbrotron and container etc inside each "slide". Maybe because the indicators are white so I can't see them - in which case how to I either budge the indicators up a bit or move the grey box down a bit, so that the white indicators will sit on top of the grey? I've spent hours trying to fix it but I'm fairly new to HMTL/CSS/JS etc so clearly missing something! Many thanks for your help.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol>
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
         <section class="jumbotron text-center">
            <div class="container">
               <h1 class="display-4">Slide 1</h1>
               <p class="lead text-muted">Sample sentence 1</p>
            </div>
         </section>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
         <section class="jumbotron text-center">
            <div class="container">
               <h1 class="display-4">Slide 2</h1>
               <p class="lead text-muted">Sample sentence 2</p>
            </div>
         </section>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
         <section class="jumbotron text-center">
            <div class="container">
               <h1 class="display-4">Slide 3</h1>
               <p class="lead text-muted">Sample sentence 3</p>
            </div>
         </section>
      </div>
   </div>
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: They are there, you have either bad sight or bad monitor. With `.carousel-control-next,.carousel-control-prev { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.42);}` you'll see them. Also note that your question is currently off-topic. You should delete it.

Comment: @tao I agree. I can see them too.

Comment: I see them under the slides. Maybe try add margin to the indicators list to move them up:
<ol class="carousel-indicators" style="margin-bottom: 40px">

Comment: Thanks Stastny that worked! Sorry all, my monitor is indeed rubbish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed some css to view the indicators clearly. You can check this.

```css
.carousel-control-next-icon, .carousel-control-prev-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: no-repeat 50%/100% 100%;
    background-color: #686161 !important;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px #000000a1;
    background-size: initial !important;
}

.carousel .jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: unset;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol>
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
         <section class="jumbotron text-center">
            <div class="container">
               <h1 class="display-4">Slide 1</h1>
               <p class="lead text-muted">Sample sentence 1</p>
            </div>
         </section>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
         <section class="jumbotron text-center">
            <div class="container">
               <h1 class="display-4">Slide 2</h1>
               <p class="lead text-muted">Sample sentence 2</p>
            </div>
         </section>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
         <section class="jumbotron text-center">
            <div class="container">
               <h1 class="display-4">Slide 3</h1>
               <p class="lead text-muted">Sample sentence 3</p>
            </div>
         </section>
      </div>
   </div>
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change arrows color and will see them

```css
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23000' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5L4.25 4l2.5-2.5L5.25 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}
.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23000' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5L3.75 4l-2.5 2.5L2.75 8l4-4-4-4z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol>
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
         <section class="jumbotron text-center">
            <div class="container">
               <h1 class="display-4">Slide 1</h1>
               <p class="lead text-muted">Sample sentence 1</p>
            </div>
         </section>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
         <section class="jumbotron text-center">
            <div class="container">
               <h1 class="display-4">Slide 2</h1>
               <p class="lead text-muted">Sample sentence 2</p>
            </div>
         </section>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
         <section class="jumbotron text-center">
            <div class="container">
               <h1 class="display-4">Slide 3</h1>
               <p class="lead text-muted">Sample sentence 3</p>
            </div>
         </section>
      </div>
   </div>
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

In this part `fill='%23000'` the `000` stands for the color.

Answer (score -1):

I can see them just fine. Change the background colour to black or a darker shade to view them. :)

[image]